# return value from datepickerCallback function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datepicker, httprequest

I am new  to Angular js, and for my application i am using a datePickerCallback function to get the date selected. How can i return the value of this function ? i actually want to get the date selected and pass it in a http request to get the data corresponding to this date.

```
 self.datePickerCallbackFrom = function(val) {
  if (typeof(val) === 'undefined') {
     console.log('Date not selected');
  } else {
     console.log('Selected date is : ', val);
     self.dateFrom = val;
  }
};
```

HTML:

```
<ionic-datepicker date="exCtrl.dateFrom" 
                  disablepreviousdates="false" 
                  disablefuturedates="true" 
                  callback="exCtrl.datePickerCallbackFrom" 
                  title="exCtrl.titleFrom">
```

Comment: We need more information on the date picker you are using to understand this question a little better.

Comment: i am using the ionic-datepicker  here is the HTML part    <ionic-datepicker date="exCtrl.dateFrom" disablepreviousdates="false"  disablefuturedates="true" callback="exCtrl.datePickerCallbackFrom" title="exCtrl.titleFrom">

Comment: where exCtrl is the controller where i declare the function datePickerCallbackFrom.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have to pass callback as an option not a html attribute.

https://github.com/rajeshwarpatlolla/ionic-datepicker#readme

```
   var options = {
      callback: function (val) {  //Mandatory
        if(typeof(val) === 'undefined') {
           console.log('Date not selected');
        } else {
           console.log('Selected date is : ', val);
           self.dateFrom = val;
        }
      }
    };

    $scope.openDatePicker = function(){
      ionicDatePicker.openDatePicker(options);
    };
```

Comment: Thank you inoabrian for your answer, but i get this error Unknown provider: ionicDatePickerProvider eventhough  i have Specified  the path of ionic-datepicker.bundle.min.js in my  index.html file, and i have included ionicDatePicker in my controller. am i missing something ?